# Why is a function of x considered constant when $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x)$

Tags: calculus

For instance, during the proof of the derivative of $\sin x$,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin (x+h) - \sin x}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x \cosh + \sin h\cos x - \sin x}{h}$$

According to the properties of limits, we can seperate this addition into two limits

$$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin x \cos h - \sin x}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h \cos x}{h}$$

**The next thing it does is factors out $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ from the limits because "they are constants."  Why are they constants? They are functions which take any real number.  This is what I don't understand.**

$$= \sin x\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos h - 1}{h} + \cos x\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$$

Comment: They are constants with respect to $h$. That is, as $h$ varies, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ do not change their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative is being derived at a fixed point. Geometrically, a chord is drawn passing through (x,f(x)) and (x+h,f(x+h)). The tangent line is obtained by drawing the line closer to the fixed point so that h becomes zero. The derivative is obtained by limit the h to zero but the value of (x,f(x)) remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to understand is that your limit depends on h not on x (for a particular value of x).

Yes I understand than x is a variable but for a particular value of x the limit only depends on h.